# Texts always in center and right, how?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am sorry I know it's simple question but I can't make this happen now.

I want one text always will be in center and another in right.

But when texts is too loo long they come to each other.

Let's say I want second text always be in the right and first text is in center but when one of these texts is too long the centered texts have to move left.

How could I do this?

I write this but it doesn't work properly.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/workout_footer_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/workout_header_height"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/review_comments_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/review_top_text_size"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/review_write_label"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/review_write_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_white"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/review_top_text_size"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sounds like `maxWidth` may be useful in combination with the answer(s) below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `layout_toLeftOf="@+id/review_write_label"` in your first TextView, remove that line and add `layout_toRightOf="@id/review_comments_label"` to your second TextView to make sure the first view stays centered and the second view stays to the right.

**Update**

Then make the second view's width match parent and set it's gravity to right. This will right justify the text in a container that stretches from the right edge of the centered TextView to the right edge of the parent thanks to the match_parent width.

Comment: but in this case text isn't always in right position.

Comment: @pmb take a look at my edit. If you need .ore code I can add it later but I'm using my phone and coding from there is a joke

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="text1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="text2" />                
        </LinearLayout>
```